# How I can deserialize C# datetime in python?

Tags: c#, python, datetime, serialization

I need to convert a date from c # to python. The data format is json. The data contained in the json formatted as: / Date (1373338800000). Must be transformed into a valid date for the python.

Comment: A date is a date irrespective of the programming language

Comment: @karthikr: But you do have to understand what a C#-generated timestamp like `1373338800000` means (it's not as if this is defined by JSON or anything), so it's a valid question.

Comment: if you can not help, not hinder.

Comment: In the future, it would help to show actual JSON, not an approximation. Is that `Date (1373338800000)` inside a string? By itself?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like unix timestamp with milliseconds.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1373338800000") / 1000)
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 8, 20, 0)
```

Comment: Almost, but you'll want to divide by 1000, because `fromtimestamp` takes seconds, not millis. (Edited so you don't have to.)

Comment: Note that there's no good way of telling whether this timestamp is GMT or local without some kind of outside knowledge. (For example, if you run the C# program locally and get it to dump out the current date and it comes out 9 hours in the future and you're in GMT-9, it's probably local. Of course if you live in GMT, that doesn't help…)

Comment: I need that time part of the result and not getting ignored 00:00:00.

Comment: @user2566498: The time part isn't ignored, nor is it 00:00:00. You've got a `datetime` object representing 8 July 2013 at 20:00.